# push DetailViewController when popping MasterViewcontroller

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

In my iPad master detail application, I have a master view controller with tableview in it an a detail view. When user clicks on a row, it pushes another master view and detail view, now when I click on the back button on the master view, only the master view pops back. I need to know how to popback detail view controller or even push it when user clicks on master view back button (I have set Navigation bar hidden in detail view and wish to keep the same)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when clicking on back button, the `viewWillDisappear` method is called. So yes, you  can push the desired detail view controller when this method is called on your master view controller:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   //Push desired detail view controller
   //If you want to use tags, make sure you set a tag for the view property of each master view controller before you push it to the stack
   if (self.view.tag == 1) {
     //For example, assuming views are tagged from 0, this is second master view controller 
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, however the problem is it works both when popping from 2nd master view to 1st master and also when pushing 3rd master view from 2nd. I need it to work only when popping  2nd to 1st.

Comment: That's easy, you just set a `tag` for each master view controller: `1,2,3, etc` and compare it each time to know which master is the current one. Or, another way is to compare the title of the navigation bar if you use a different one each time. Let me know.